# Return rest of the line after string in other file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

`main.sh` file:

```sh
function checkSettings() {
  setting="$1 : " #| sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"
  # awk -F '${setting}' '{print $2}' settings.tropx
  # sed 's/.*${setting} //' settings.tropx
  # sed -nr '/MOM:/ s/.*MOM:([^"]+).*/\1/p' settings.tropx
}
checkSettings "Debug Mode"
sleep 100
```

All three options weren't able to return what I wanted from this file

`settings.tropx` file:

```
Debug Mode : (OFF) | ON
Animations : (ALL) | SOME | NONE
Default Scripts : (SHOW) | HIDE
MOM : Yes
```

I expect the function to give something like `(ALL) | SOME | NONE` if I pass the argument `Animations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep` and `cut` (read `man grep cut`):

```
function checksettings() {
  grep "^$1 :" settings.tropx | \
    cut "-d:" -f2- | \
      cut "-d " -f2-
}
# use like this ($1 is the string)
rightside="$(checksettings "$1")"
# Beware! What happens if you pass "Aminations" (a typo)?
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`

```
#!/bin/bash

function checkSettings() {
   awk -F ' *: *' -v arg="$1" '$1 == arg {print $2}' settings.tropx
}

checkSettings 'Debug Mode'
```